# C++ fabs(long double) compiler warning

Tags: c++, absolute-value, long-double

I want to have the absolute value of a `long double`.

According to `<cmath>` or `<math.h>`, the following is available:

```
     double fabs (double x);
     float fabs (float x);
     long double fabs (long double x);
```

However, when doing `long double ld = fabs(static_cast<long double>(0));`, I get the following warning (LLVM 7.1):

`Absolute value function 'fabs' given an argument of type 'long double' but has parameter of type 'double' which may cause truncation of value`

How come?

What other ways are there to get the absolute value of a `long double`?

**Edit:**

`std::abs` eventually did the job. However, `std::fabs` didn't. As was pointed out in the comments, this may be due to a non-conforming implementation.

Comment: Did you verify in the public headers if the function is implemented, or did you only check the docs?

Comment: Only the docs, assuming this is standard. Apparently, I was wrong (?)

Comment: Maybe try `std::fabs` or `std::abs`?

Comment: The standard is whatever should be implemented, though that doesn't mean this is in practice. Where possible I'll try to look at the headers as they match the implementation.

Comment: as far as I can tell only `<cmath>` is required to have `long double fabs (long double x);`.  If including `<cmath>` and using `std::fabs` does not work then you have a non conforming implementation.

Comment: This is pretty cool, actually. Usually people post about the surprising aftermath of the opposite resulting from a `using namespace std;` lurking in the code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to cppreference http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/math/fabs and http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/fabs the C version of `fabs` in the global namespace only accepts a `double` argument and you would need to use `fabsl`. However `std::fabs` or `std::abs` should have the proper `long double` overloads for you.